# How to use this type of function?

Tags: javascript

In a code I have a function built this way.

```
(function init () {
})
```

And every time I try to use a function inside it, an Uncaught ReferenceError error occurs: **** is not defined

```
(function init() {
  var norm = ["cookie", "toUTCString", "createObjectURL", "newTab", "javascript:window.focus()", "_self", "_blank", "blurByAlert"];
  (function(value, count) {
    var fn = function(selected_image) {
      for (; --selected_image;) {
        value["push"](value["shift"]());
      }
    };
    fn(++count);
  })(norm, 8);

  var $ = function(i, fn) {
    i = i - 0;
    var id = norm[i];
    return id;
  };

})
```

If I remove (function init () {
}) it works. But I can not simply remove. I need to know to use functions that are within function init () out of scope.

***Visit the website to see the issue reproduce correctly. My script source has no https and this conflicts with the stackoverflow html editor***
http://noise.combr.co/index6.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Captcha</title>
 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

   <script src="http://noise.combr.co/script.js"></script>

<script>
   console.log($('0x001'));
</script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <h3>Only Test </h3>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `(function init () { })()` with `()` at the end? Because if you don't have that, yet you do have the function surrounded by `(` and `)` the code makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping a function in `(` and `)` puts it into an expression context. That makes it a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) instead of a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

While function declarations create variables in the same scope, expressions do not.

You aren't doing *anything* with the expression. There's no assignment on the left hand side. There's no `()` to call it in the right hand side. The function is created and then immediately discarded (just as `("a string that isn't used")` would be).

Remove the `(` and `)` from around it. Use a function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about  self invoking functions, without the () at the end it won't be called. 
A self invooking function normally looks like:

```
(function(x){
   console.log(x);
 })("Hello, World!");
```

I recomend you read on this site: https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/js-self-invoking-functions.html